# How to add an option in every selects with same id

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add an option at selects with the same id.

Here is how my html looks like

```
  <div>
    <select id="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here is how my html looks like but it changes one the first select

```
$('#essai').append($('<option>my-option</option>'));
```

Here is the result i would like

```
  <div>
    <select id="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>my-option</option>
    </select>
    <select id="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>my-option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: 1st You can't give same id . **ID is UNIQUE** but you can give **Class** for later select if you need

Comment: IDs must be unique

Comment: "1st You can give same id" I think what he means is CANT. He is right, you can not give 2 select input same ID as ID needs to be unique, you use class for that.

Duplicate ID will cause one or both drop down to be ignored

Comment: Yeah haha sorry for miss spelling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id must be unique. Use `class` to do this. Use `$.each` for pass on all class.

```js
$.each($(".essai"), function(){
  $(this).append($('<option>my-option</option>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select class="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: There's no need for `$.each` or all the extra calls to `$()` here. Simply `$(".essai").append('<option>my-option</option>');` (note passing the string to `append`).

Comment: Yes no need each. But with this he can be define different value if he want

Answer (score 2):

Change your **ID** to **class**

`$('.essai')` will select class change `#` ti `.`

```
. will let you select Class
```

```js
$('.essai').append($('<option>my-option</option>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select class="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**id** must be unique. so here instead of using id, you should use class.

```
$('.essai').append($('<option>my-option</option>'));
```

now it will update all options.

```
<div>
    <select class="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>my-option</option>
    </select>
    <select class="essai">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>my-option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```